# how can i compare the columns from different lines in awk

Tags: linux, awk

Suppose i have this file

```
var1 300
var1 400
var3 600
var1 200
```

Now how can i compare the `$1(from line 1) == $1 (from line 2)`

basically i just want to add the columns if the name is equal

Only with `awk`

The output should br

```
var1 900
var3 600
```

Comment: the solution is simple BUT you need to post your expected output for us to know what exactly to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this over @Guru's solution if your file is large and/or you care about preserving the input order and your input is sorted on the first field:

```
$ awk '(NR>1) && ($1!=p){print p, s; s=0} {p=$1; s+=$2} END{print p, s}' file
var1 700
var3 600
```

Comment: thanks buddy ,  but i am confused with two things. 1.) Does awk process the file line by line and in order. Also what if i have  `var1 = 200` is also after the var 2 , then what will ahppen

Comment: 1) yes 2) then you'll get a 2nd instance of var1 with it's own count that started after var2 in your output. The logic is to compare the current line's $1 with the previous lines $1 and if they're different then print the sum for that previous $1 and reset the sum to zero.

Comment: @user55711, at least this method should filter out the bulk of your huge file. Then you can sort it and pass it through Ed's program for a second pass.

Comment: @user55711, don't. Use `sort`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for (i in a)print i, a[i];}' file
var1 700
var3 600
```

Comment: i want to know that if i have the file of 5GB in size, can i use above method

Comment: @user55711, awk won't have trouble processing a huge file because it basically reads a line at a time. Since this method creates an associative array with column 1 as keys, the question is how many unique keys are there, and what is their size?

Comment: @glennjackman may be 1 million , will it work with that amount

Comment: If your computer has only a tiny amount of memory, it might be slow. Try it and let us know.